# jQuery listener for PHP event

Tags: php, jquery, forms, authentication, event-listener

I have a simple form submission and in my process.php file I check each field for its valitity. If it fails, I'm using key/value pairs in $_SESSION to display an alert message on the login page.

The alert message is displayed on a div (with some bootstrap styling, if that matters) that is set to .hide when the page loads.

Is there a jQuery function or event listener I can use to detect the PHP echo and .toggle the alert box?

Heres my relevant code as it stands:

```
<div class="alert alert-error alert-block" id="error-box">
    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['first_name'])) { 
        echo $_SESSION['first_name'];
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['last_name'])) { 
        echo $_SESSION['last_name'];
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) { 
        echo $_SESSION['email'];
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['passlen'])) { 
        echo $_SESSION['passlen'];
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['passmatch'])) { 
        echo $_SESSION['passmatch'];
        }           
?>
</div>
```

And:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#error-box").hide();     
});
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery and PHP arent processing at the same time, one is server side, the other is client side. You can check is the error box is empty, if that is the case, hide it (though im not sure what you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest thing would be to check if `#error-box` contains any text:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($.trim($("#error-box").text()).length < 1) {
        $("#error-box").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: That one wins the day. Thanks man. I also learned a few new jQuery commands.

Answer (score 0):

php runs on the server and and javascript runs in the browser, after the php code is executed and translated to html. Rather than hiding/showing with javascript, only insert the error message if there are any errors.

```
<?php
// validate your form

if ($errors) : ?>
<div class="alert alert-error alert-block" id="error-box">
    print your errors
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then you don't need javascript to hide/show anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a wrong approach. As you say you have a simple form i expect you dont use ajax. So by calling your php script you will have a page reload and you can just echo the box if you need.

```
<?php $fields = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'passlen', 'passmatch');?>

<?php if ($_SESSION['first_name'] || $_SESSION['last_name'] || $_SESSION['email'] || $_SESSION['passlen'] || $_SESSION['passmatch'] ): ?>

    <div class="alert alert-error alert-block" id="error-box">
        <?php
            foreach($fields as $_field){
               if (isset($_SESSION[$_field])) { 
                 echo $_SESSION[$_field];
               }
            }

    ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Well it could be done better, but it shows what i want to tell!